# How to get full Gmail API message when clipped?

Tags: google-api, gmail-api

Gmail messages are clipped when body is exceeding 102kb. In the UI one can get the entire message with a link in the bottom of the page, however the Gmail API does not display it.

Following the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get), I did not manage to find any solution whatever the format chosen. The body is well printed but not entire (and no link to read the rest). Am I missing something ?

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43463046/edit) the question to be on-topic: include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer : listing messages under threads renders messages with no body limit :)

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/list) does not mention this difference but tried and approved.